# Доступ к сайту работающему через ipv6

Tags: ip, ipv6

Подскажите пожалуйста, а, то я совсем запутался: как я это понимаю - вот к примеру есть сайты, сервера которых работают через провайдеров у которых есть оборудование с поддержкой IP протокола версии 6.
Может ли клиент подключится к этому сайту, если делает запрос к сайту через своего провайдера, у которого есть только оборудование ipv4 ?

Ну для примера вот у фейсбука вроде бы название сайта в привязкой адресации ipv6: [www.v6.facebook.com](http://www.v6.facebook.com)

Но я не могу из браузера открыть эту страницу.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/207562/

Comment: в общем на винде не пробовал, а на убунте миредо, это было давно, но очень даже работал из коробки.